# ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus Denied After Authorized In Settings

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I am attempting to more gracefully handle denied contact book permissions, but I have found a scenario that doesn't work properly. I am running Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0.

First I explain why the permission is relevant to the app experience and then when they decide it should be allowed they can tap a button with calls:

```
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(nil) {
    (granted:Bool, err:CFError!) in
    if(granted){
        // Get contacts
    }
}
```

Should they decline the iOS permission dialog, I prompt them later using the following code after checking `ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()`:

```
func evaluateContactAccess(requestCompleted: (granted: Bool) -> ()) {
    let status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus();
    switch status {
    case .Authorized:
        requestCompleted(granted: true);
    case .NotDetermined:
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(nil) {
            (granted:Bool, err:CFError!) in
                requestCompleted(granted: granted);
        };
    case .Restricted, .Denied:
        let alertController = UIAlertController(
            title: "Contact Access Disabled",
            message: "Message about access here...",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        let openAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .Default) { (action) in

            if let url = NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {

                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
            }
        }
        alertController.addAction(openAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil);

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "checkAndProceed", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }
}

func checkAndProceed() {
    let status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()
    switch status {
    case .Authorized:
        // get contacts
    case .NotDetermined, .Restricted, .Denied:
        // debugger says status = .Denied at this point every time
    }
}
```

Now the app's iOS settings page opens accordingly and the user is given the opportunity to grant contact access. Let's say they grant access to the contact book and switch back to the app - no matter how many times I call `ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()` after the app resumes it always returns `ABAuthorizationStatus.Denied` as if it didn't detect the user changing the permission to Authorized in the app's iOS settings page.

I filed a bug with Apple just in case, but I was wondering if anyone else had a trick to get this working.

Thanks!

Comment: You do realize that this whole API is deprecated in iOS 9, yes? I mean, we could go into detail on this, but it won't be worth it if, as you are supposed to, you just drop the whole thing and come into the modern world of the contacts. However, if you really want to probe this further, then please show your actual code. Show how you are testing the authorization status.

Comment: @matt Of course most apps still support iOS 8 and must use the old API.

Comment: @matt Yes I know all about the new contact framework, but I want to support iOS 8 right now and would rather not include an "if supported" block

Comment: Okay, fine. Well, this does work in my code (for example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch18p713addressBook/ch31p973addressBook/ViewController.swift), so as I already said, show more details if you want more help.

Comment: @matt thank you for the example. I will update my question, but I am using exactly the same method you have in your example. I wonder if this issue was newly introduced with iOS 9.

Comment: @matt added more implementation. Also tried in iOS 8.1 with the same results.

Comment: I don't mean to be lazy about this, but do you suppose you could just copy out my code and paste it right into your own project and try it? It's perfectly possible that you've found a bug in iOS here. In my code, coming back to the app should cause us (when the app activates) to test for permission again, exactly in case we were granted permission while we were suspended in the background. I'm sure it used to work!

Comment: @matt no dice... wonder if it is somehow swift 2.0 although that doesn't make sense... How has no one else seen this? It seems like a big bug to me.

Comment: Okay, so I updated my example so that it runs on iOS 9 / Swift 2 in spite of the deprecations, and it works fine. Here's how I tested. The app launches: the system authorization alert appears: deny. Tap the first button (Find Myself). My alert appears asking the user to authorize. Accept so that we are taken to Settings, and throw the switch. Go back to my app. Tap the first button again. My alert _doesn't_ appear asking the user to authorize. That's because it knows we are now authorized!

Comment: Voting to close because I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @matt wth... even pushing this to my phone has the same issue. I guess I will keep digging. Thanks for giving it a shot on your end.

Comment: Well, I've shown you my complete code, and I have described my testing procedure in detail. You have done neither of those things, despite my repeated requests. - Also, the fact that you say "debugger says .Denied" is a bad sign; you can't test this feature while running from the Xcode debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given sufficient information about what your code is and how you are testing, despite my repeated requests, so at this point I can only guess. And my guess is that your testing procedure is flawed. You cannot test this feature while running in the Xcode debugger. If you untether your device and test purely on the device, you will find that when you return to your app from Settings, if your app then checks again for the authorization status, it gets the authorization status right.